# Pure swift framework without giving the source code/xcodeproject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, static-libraries

I have been following framework making tutorials for building my frameworks and one thing I noticed that after building the framework, the example states to use the .Xcodeproject along with other codes needs to be referenced to the example project to use the framework, that should not happen, if so happened, what is the need of the framework as there will be no security of the code?

can anyone throw some light on this to resolve the doubt?

Comment: Check https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: My context is Swift...and as far as I know static libraries are not supported.

Comment: Hum, true, • Xcode does not support building static libraries that include Swift code. (17181019) http://mazur.me/SwiftInFlux/docs/beta5.pdf